# Drupal jQuery namespacing

Tags: jquery, namespaces, drupal-7

I can use the short and convenient dollar jQuery notation I am using the following code structure:

```
(function($) {
    $('div#webform-component-team-name').css('background', 'blue');
    alert('testing!');
    console.log('working...!');
})(jQuery);
```

But, I find nothing works with the exception of my alert and console.log statements. These statement work fine but the second line of to alter the background-color (or anything else beginning with **$**) does not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the alert and console.log functions should work without jQuery (console.log depending on your browser). So the first thing I would check is that jQuery is actually being loaded OK in your page and is available before you run this anonymous function.

As a useful aside there is very good explanation of using self-executing functions for namespacing javascript / jQuery [here](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/).

It extends the syntax you used, as in this example:

```
(function( skillet, $, undefined ) {
// do stuff here
}( window.skillet = window.skillet || {}, jQuery ));
```

and shows how to make functions public and private.